# Code does not work as supposed after converting my development using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am converting my PHP/mySQL code to PDO but I am having some difficulties. Below I have added the exact code I am using with example for better understanding. My goal is to show the `name` from the DB that their time compared with the one on input differ by 2 hours.

this is the code

SELECT * FROM events WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR , TIME, :input ) < 2

this is my database

```
name                        date
3D Brave                    2012-07-21 17:00:00
Bol Bachchan                2012-07-21 18:00:00
A Royal Affair              2012-07-21 19:00:00
Not Suitable For Children   2012-07-21 23:00:00
```

If the `$input` is `2012-07-20 18:00` or `2012-07-20 20:00` then I get all the results as below, but it should show only those that have a difference 2 hours

```
3D Brave
Bol Bachchan
A Royal Affair
Not Suitable For Children
```

Comment: Does it work properly when you do it in PHPMyAdmin (or similar)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're querying the difference from the column `TIME`, but in the table schema, it's called `date`.

Corrected query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM events 
  WHERE ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR , `date`, "2012-07-21 18:00:00")) < 2;
```

#### What I did:

- Changed column name to `date`
- Added `ABS()` function (so it now looks both forwards and backwards).

**[The result of that query.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f250/16/0)**